# Remove carriage return from variable interpolation

Tags: bash

Not a Bash developer here, so probably this is simple.
I have a Bash script that port-forwards k8s pods (pf.sh):

```
POD=$(kubectl get pods | awk '{print $1}' | grep -e $1)
echo $POD
kubectl port-forward $POD 5433:5432
```

So you maybe call it with:

> pf.sh some-main-part-of-a-pod-name

The problem is that when I echo $POD in the second line, the variable is exactly as I want it to use it in the third line. But when I try injecting it in the third line I get:

> pods "some-main-part-of-a-pod-name-57f485d4f5-fdl4p\r" not found

Notice the carriage return at the end. Can I avoid this somehow?

More info: I'm using MobaXTerm bash flavor on a Windows laptop.
And the input of the get pods command will look something like:

> some-main-part-of-a-pod-name-57f485d4f5-fdl4p  2/2  Running               0                 2d1h

Just to reiterate: there's no problem on the assignment of the POD variable. The problem seems to be on the third line, when I do the variable interpolation. It's in THAT line that I get the carriage return at the end. Not on the $POD (at least not according to the echo of the second line).

The echo $POD actually correctly returns:

> some-main-part-of-a-pod-name-57f485d4f5-fdl4p

**UPDATE!!! Figured it out!**
I simply can go by without the variable creation and interpolate the whole thing.
Only one line:

`kubectl port-forward $(kubectl get pods | awk '{print $1}' | grep -e $1) 5433:5432`

Comment: Why not simply remove them as early as possible, i.e. `kubectl get pods|dos2unix|...`?

Comment: You could show how `POD` variable is by using `echo ${POD@Q}`  and drop *cariage return* by `POD=${POD%$'\r'}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
POD=$(kubectl get pods | perl -sane 's/\r//g; print $F[0] if /$regex/' -- -regex=$1)
```

Comment: pods "\r" not found

Comment: Thanks to give a sample input of raw `kubectl get pods` by editing your original post, not in comments

Comment: And explain which OS you use

Comment: A simpler fix is to add `sub(/\r/, "")` to the OP's Awk script, though they'll probably want to get rid of the [useless `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) too.

Comment: @tripleee Depending on `kubectl get pods` outuput, Having to fork to `perl` or `awk` may be useless, if output is only few lines.